# ¿Cuál es el significado del tipo de variable que tiene el mismo nombre que su clase?

Tags: java, c#

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
class Person {
     private Person variable; 
}
```

No entiendo que significa que exista un atributo `Person` dentro de la clase. ¿No se supone que debo poner un tipo como integer o string, etc?

Comment: Person es una objeto. Java contiene datos primitivos (integer, etc) y clases como String, objetos creados por nosotros mismos o objetos de la API de Java. C# maneja el mismo principio

Comment: @josego eso es un intento de respuesta (que no debería ir como comentario). Te recomiendo ampliarlo y publicarlo

Comment: Si haz solucionado tu inconveniente podrías poner como solucionado a la respuesta que te ha ayudado. gracias

Comment: Es un campo, igual que cualquier otro, sólo que su modificado es `private`... De esa forma puedes crear listas enlazadas y otras estructuras...

Answer (score 4):

En Java existen dos tipos de variables:

1. De tipo primitivo: de tipo numérico (enteras: `byte`,`short`,`int`,`long`; flotantes: `float`,`double`), de tipo booleano (`boolean`) y de tipo caracter (`char`).
2. De tipo referencia (o de objetos, de clase, no hay una única definición en la literatura). Aquí se encuentran todos los tipos para los que se define una clase, de acuerdo al estandar de Java. El ejemplo más común es la clase `String`.

Cuando usted define una clase en Java (como su clase `Person`) puede incluir variables de cualquier tipo como miembros de la clase, por ejemplo:

```
public class Persona {
    int edad;
    String nombre;
    float peso;
    Persona mejorAmigo;
    //...
}
```

Estas variables dentro de una clase son llamadas por la documentación 'campos'. La anterior porción de código define una clase que se llama Persona que contiene los siguientes campos:

1. Una variable llamada edad de tipo `int` (primitiva: almacenará números enteros)
2. Una variable llamada nombre de tipo `String` (de referencia: almacenará una representación de una cadena de caracteres, junto a más propiedades y métodos para operar)
3. Una variable llamada peso de tipo `float` (primitiva: almacenará números flotantes)
4. Una variable llamada mejorAmigo de tipo `Persona`.

Los campos de una clase pueden ser de cualquier tipo, tanto primitivos como de referencia. E incluso (como la variable llamada mejorAmigo) pueden ser del mismo tipo que de la clase que se está definiendo. Es decir: en Java es válido en una clase tener un campo cuyo tipo de dato es el de la misma clase. En tiempo de compilación Java detecta que la sintaxis es correcta (y como ya ha definido una clase de tipo Persona, el compilador ya sabe a qué tipo de clase `Persona` hace referencia el campo mejorAmigo. Este tipo de declaraciones es habitual en este lenguaje. Semánticamente significa que un objeto de tipo `Persona` tiene un 'mejorAmigo' que también es de tipo `Persona`, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Person es una objeto. Java contiene dos tipos de datos. Los primitivos (int, boolean, short, byte, etc) y clases como String, objetos creados por nosotros mismos o objetos de la API de Java. C# maneja el mismo principio.

Cuando un Objeto de una clase contiene Objetos o tipos de datos, se los denomina aributos de clase.

Ejemplo:

```
public class Person { 
    private Person empleado;    // empleado es un objeto Person
    private int edad;           // edad es un tipo primitivo int.
    private String nombre;      // nombre es un objeto tipo string.

    ...
}
```

Podes colocar por cada clase el tipo que quieras sea tipo primitivo o objeto. Ya depende de tus necesidades

Answer (score 1):

A ver, en el sentido más literal de la pregunta, eso significa una relación recursiva, por ejemplo, un trabajador que tiene un jefe, ambos son objetos "Person".

Es solo un ejemplo, puede ser otra cosa, pero cuando hay un objeto dentro de otro que es del mismo tipo, es una relación recursiva.

Y no, no tienen porqué ser Integer, string, etc.. Puede ser cualquier tipo de dato que exista o que tu crees, por ejemplo 'Person' es un tipo de dato, aunque no lo entiendas bien aún, cualquier clase que tu crees se convierte en un 'tipo de dato' por decirlo de un modo fácil.

Un string guarda cadenas, un integer gurda enteros, un 'Person' guarda personas.. ¿entiendes? no tiene mayor ciencia.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Java y C# manejan dos tipos de datos: Tipos Primitivos y Tipos Por Referencia.

1. Tipos Primitivos: numéricos enteros (`int`, `byte`, etc.), numéricos de coma flotante (`float` y `double`, y `decimal` en C# que es utilizado para valores monetarios), booleanos (`bool`) y de caracter (`char`). Estos tipos solamente almacenan valores, no pueden contener referencias a espacios de memoria.
2. Tipos Por Referencia: son aquellos que están compuestos por una colección de tipos primitivos o tipos por referencia o ambos, es decir, que pueden contener más de un valor en su interior. Este es el caso de las clases, que contienen variables que referencian a un espacio en memoria donde se almacena el valor de esa variable en particular (atributos en C#, campos en Java). Para que quede más claro, es un "contenedor" de variables entre otras cosas, por decirlo de alguna manera sencilla.

Como dijimos, la clase es un `TIPO` (un tipo definido por el usuario, pero al fin y al cabo, para el compilador es válido), por lo tanto puede ser usado para definir una variable. Por lo tanto, al definir una variable de TIPO Person, lo que le estamos diciendo al compilador es que esa variable va a ser un objeto de tipo Person, y al ser un tipo válido puede usarse en declaraciones de variables (campos o atributos según el lenguaje que elijas).

Espero se haya entendido y aclarado la duda.

Answer (score 0):

Pues existen los tipos de datos `primitivos`, y las `clases` que son `OBJETOS` y los objetos pueden ser tipos de datos también.

Tal vez la confución aqui seria: ¿porqué una `clase` tiene una variable de su mismo tipo?

Este tipo de diseños de clases u objetos (recordemos que una clase es la representación de un objeto de la vida real; en programación orientada a objetos) se pueden presentar. Y puede ser la solución para ciertos casos, como lo muestro acontinuación siguiendo con el ejemplo de la clase Persona:

```
Persona

id      int

nombre  String

edad    int

madre   Persona

padre   Persona
```

Entonces para el diseño de esta clase, la misma clase tiene dos atributos de su mismo tipo, en este caso definí los atributos: madre y padre que también son personas.

Sin meterme mas a detalle con los tipos de datos, etc., etc., explico este punto en especifico que es lo que hace que se vea tan raro todo el asunto.

Answer (score 0):

Todos han dado excelente explicaciones sobre el tipo de dato, pero veo principalmente que el problema es de entendimiento, en el caso de la clase persona, puede contener por referencia a otra persona en un caso hipotetico de padre e hijo asi: Un Hijo tiene referencia a quien es su padre y en otro caso un padre podría tener referencia a sus hijos si esta propiedad fuera una Lista o un Arreglo.